# How change state or property of an outer / separate component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Current DOM tree is like:

```
<comp1>
  <div>
      <comp2></comp2>
      <comp3>
         <comp4 />
         <comp4 />
         .........
         .........
         .........
      </comp3>
  </div>
  <comp5></comp5>  
</comp1>
```

Component5 i.e.  is my modal. I want to set it's state and props by onclick event on

My objective is to display the detail data on a modal based on the selection.
So I need to set the state and props of modal component accordingly. How can I that in the current structure?

Answer (score 0):

The old fashioned way, which is fine for a small page, is to move all states into the root node (`comp1`). Other components become stateless. The root node passes to its children the properties they want to render, alongside the setters required to mutate the properties. For instance, `comp5` gets a property `username` which is just the value of `comp1.state.username`, plus a property `setUsername`, which is a function taking a `username` string parameter in which `comp1` uses `setState` to update its state's `username`. This way `comp5` can render *and* update the username, and other components are aware of the change (`setState` triggers a render of children).

For more complex apps, passing all these properties to children gets tedious, and you can resort to framework like `flux` and `redux`.

Answer (score 0):

i think standard way of doing it is something like this

in your react component:

```
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.state = {selectedComp4:  null
        ...
        }
    }
...
handleSelectedComp4Change (yourData) {
    this.setState({selectedComp4: yourData})
}
...
render() {
...
    return (
    <comp1>
    <div>
        <comp2></comp2>
        <comp3>
            <comp4 onSelectedComp4Change = {this.handleSelectedComp4Change}/>
            <comp4 onSelectedComp4Change = {this.handleSelectedComp4Change}/>
             ...
        </comp3>
    </div>
    <comp5 SelectedComp4={this.state.selectedComp4}></comp5>  
    </comp1>
    )
}
```

in comp4 send your data: `onClick={() => { this.props.onSelectedComp4Change(someData) }}`

in comp5 use your data in `this.props.SelectedComp4`

EDIT:

just like @Valéry said