# Open React MaterialUI modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If I have a MaterialUI icon button, rendered in the header, how do I make a modal shown when I click that button? How do I handle modals in react in general? Where should I render it and how should I make it open programatically?

Comment: Your question is generic and should ideally cite prior research. You can go over the excellent examples available on material-ui docs [on this topic](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog).

Comment: Check Dan's Abramov answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623656/how-can-i-display-a-modal-dialog-in-redux-that-performs-asynchronous-actions/35641680

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard React way is to use parent states, altering them by callbacks and sending them to children thru props. Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319013/how-change-state-or-property-of-an-outer-separate-component-in-reactjs/37320992#37320992) to similiar question.

Or another option is to invoke children methods by [refts to children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).